# Is Predator Helios 300 compatible with Ubuntu 23.10?

Tags: acer, compatibility, 23.10

i recently installed Ubuntu on a MSI Cubi and it's working perfectly and I'm working on it daily to learn better this environment, but while doing so I'm also neglecting my Predator Helios 300. Now you may ask, you installed it one time, you can do it again right? Well installing it on my Cubi was a simple task because it's a 8 year old pc that I happened to find in my garage after years of not using it, so if it had gone awry I could have cut my losses easily as I was about to throw it in the trash the same day I found it, and it's not comparable to my laptop as it's brand new and it costed me much more. So with this said could someone tell me please if my laptop is compatible with Ubuntu 23.10 (or how to find out if it works in a safe way)? my laptop is Acer Predator Helios 300 with Nvidia Geforce RTX 3060, 16 GB RAM (planning to do 32 GB) and Intel Core i7 8 core.
Disclaimer: I know this is a gaming laptop and all but I plan to program on it (like coding or experimenting with raspberry Pis, Arduinos etc...)
Thanks for the help!

Comment: if it does not or partially... filing a bugreport would be what to do.